# Method is undefined for this type ERROR

Tags: java, methods, undefined, blending

Hi I keep getting this error: Error: The method BlendRectWithWhite(int, int, int, int, int) is undefined for the type BlendablePic

here is my coding for both, I am confused about what to do as I've looked at other forum posts and they just made me more confused about what to do! Thanks!

```
import java.awt.Color;
public class IHateCompScience 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)

{
FileChooser.pickMediaPath();
BlendablePic pRef = new BlendablePic(FileChooser.pickAFile());
pRef.BlendRectWithWhite(0, 0, 300, 300, 2);
pRef.explore();

}}

public class BlendablePic extends Picture{
 public BlendablePic(String filename){
super(filename);
 }
 public void blendRectWithWhite(int xMin, int yMin, int xMax, int yMax, double a)
 {
 int x;
 x = xMin;
 while (x<= xMax)
 {
  int y;
  y = yMin;
  while(y <= yMax)
  {
    Pixel refPix = this.getPixel(x,y);
    refPix.setRed((int)Math.round(refPix.getRed() * (1.0 +a)+255*a));
    refPix.setGreen((int)Math.round(refPix.getGreen() * (1.0 +a)+255*a));
    refPix.setBlue((int)Math.round(refPix.getBlue() * (1.0 +a)+255*a));
  y= y+1;
  }
  x = x+1;
  }}
```

Comment: you are calling BlendRectWithWhite but the method is defined as blendRectWithWhite. Case matters. The method definition is the one that matches with convention. Also, based on your main class name I'm wondering if this is the right field for you...

Comment: @digitaljoel haha i just changed my major don't worry, most of the hate goes towards my TA as well. Thank you though!

Answer (score 5):

Java is case sensitive langauge.

So call the method whatever you define.

In your case.

```
 pRef.blendRectWithWhite(0, 0, 300, 300, 2);
```

Comment: oh man, literally knew it was something simple. Thanks!

Comment: @user2129821 Do accept answer on SO. if its solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
pRef.BlendRectWithWhite(0, 0, 300, 300, 2);
```

should be

```
pRef.blendRectWithWhite(0, 0, 300, 300, 2);
```